# I want to extract values from an array and use them in a string expression

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I am trying to do a for loop of a nonlinear fit where one of the coefficients changes values with each iteration. These values are in an array called YoungMod. I have:

```
for k=1:size(DataAll,3)
    ft = fittype('E1*(YoungMod(k))-b*t','coefficients',{'E1','b'},'independent', 't','dependent','depth','options',fo);
    [FittedData{k},gof{k}] = fit(DataAll(:,3,k),DataAll(:,1,k),ft1); %{k});
    coeffs{k}=coeffvalues(FittedData{k});
end
```

The error message I receive is:

```
    Error using fittype>iTestCustomModelEvaluation (line 726)
    Expression
    E1*(YoungMod(k))-b*t
    is not a valid MATLAB expression, has non-scalar coefficients, or cannot be evaluated:
    Error in fittype expression ==>
   (E1*YoungMod(k))-b*t
    ??? Undefined function 'YoungMod' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

To me, it looks like the issue is that the string is reading YoungMod*(k) instead of taking the k value of the YoungMod array. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead to make sure k is evaluated as a variable and not a string:

```
ft = fittype(['E1*(YoungMod(' num2str(k) '))-b*t'],'coefficients',{'E1','b'},'independent', 't','dependent','depth','options',fo);
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but this still wasn't doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem using a dummy variable and the 'problem' option for fittype:

```
for k=1:size(DataAll,3)
    ym = YoungMod(k)
    ft = fittype('E1*(ym)-b*t','coefficients',{'E1','b'},'independent', 't','dependent','depth','options',fo,'problem','ym');
    [FittedData{k},gof{k}] = fit(DataAll(:,3,k),DataAll(:,1,k),ft,'problem',ym);
    coeffs{k}=coeffvalues(FittedData{k});
end
```